# Multiprocessing in python for mqtt data

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, mqtt

I have a question regarding the use of multiprocessing .
I have a set up, where I need to subscribe mqtt data and do some process on the data in python.
Everything should happen in real time ie whenever a data is received from the mqtt subscribe node the second function should start their process.

I have tried using process manager ,so that I can share the data among the process.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

from multiprocessing import Manager, Process

topics_to_subscribe=['test/topic1','test/topic2','test/topic3','test/topic4']

def process(buffer1,buffer2):
    #do some task 

def mqtt_subscribe(buffer):

    def on_connect(client,userdata,flags,rc):

       for topic in topics_to_subscribe:
        
           client.subscribe(topic)
      
    def on_message(client, userdata, message):

        buffer.append(message.payload)

    client = mqtt.Client()
 
    client.on_connect = on_connect

    client.on_message = on_message


    broker_address="192.168.1.184"
    client.connect(broker_address)

   client.loop_forever()

def mqtt_subscribe2(buffer2):

    def on_connect(client,userdata,flags,rc):

      
        
          client.subscribe('topic1')
      
    def on_message(client, userdata, message):

        buffer2.append(message.payload)

   client = mqtt.Client()
 
   client.on_connect = on_connect

   client.on_message = on_message


   broker_address="192.168.1.184"
   client.connect(broker_address)

   client.loop_forever()
   
if __name__ == '__main__':

  manager = Manager()
  client = mqtt.Client()

  buffer1=manager.list()
  buffer2=manager.list()
  p1 = Process(target=mqtt_subscriber2, args=(buffer2))
  p2 = Process(target=mqtt_subscriber2, args=(buffer2))

  p3 = Process(target=process, args=(buffer1,buffer2))
  
  p1.start()
  p2.start()
  p3.start()
```

Please find the script which i wrote. i am just a beginner so please correct me if it is wrong.

so i have 2 functions mqtt_subscribe1 and mqtt_subscribe2 ,which will append the values from the mqtt topic to separate list.
I need to do a process with the values appended to the list simultaneously ie whenevr a value is appended ,it should undergo some process in the function 'process'.

the problem with this script is it does not work parrallely.

Appreciate if someone could provide some leads.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't work in parallel?

Comment: the mqtt_subscriber 1 and 2 function is used to append the data from mqtt subscriber in node red.So my aim is to get values appended to the buffer parallely.But now whenever  
 the lbuffer 1 in mqtt_subscriber 1 is appending. the code does not append the value in buffer2.